# std::copy/memcpy/memmove optimizations

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, c++98

I looked into the GCC STL (4.6.1) and saw that `std::copy()` uses an optimized version in case the builtin `__is_trivial()` evaluates to `true`.

Since the `std::copy()` and `std::reverse_copy()` templates are very useful for copying elements in arrays, I would like to use them. However, I have some types (which are results of template instantiations) that are structs that contain some trivial values, no pointers and have no copy constructor or assignment operator.

Is G++ smart enough to figure out that my type in fact is trivial? Is there any way in C++98 to make sure an STL implementation knows that my type is trivial?

I guess that in C++11, things will become convenient using the `is_trivial<>` type trait. Is this right?

Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry for being so late with this, but here is an example of a pretty simple `Type` class that is not trivial to GCC and llvm. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Spec;

template <typename TValue, typename TSpec>
class Type
{
public:
    TValue value;

    Type() : value(0) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::cerr << "__is_trivial(...) == "
              << __is_trivial(Type<char, Spec>) << '\n';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++03 PODs forbit default constructors too if I recall, which is probably what prevents that from being trivial.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks, I think that is the explanation. Together with Mathieu's answer, this answers my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has been some debate over what `trivial` meant.

For example, your example is not trivially constructible as far as I can tell (`std::is_trivially_default_constructible` would return false I think).

In your case, I think you would need the new trait [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable), which is more fine grained. So... upgrade your compiler ?

Answer (score 4):

`__is_trivial` gives the right value for all types.

You can't rely on any paticular STL implementation to use it, although if the compiler vendor supplied it then it probably does contain various compiler-specific improvements behinds the scenes.

C++11's `std::is_trivial` is merely standardising this feature, there's no reason for an implementation not to use it.

Comment: Apparently, `__is_trivial` cannot deduce whether a type is trivially copyable. :( See the example in my update.