# Are the restrictions of std::copy more relaxed than std::memcopy?

Tags: c++, c, stl, memcpy, memmove

With [regard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913747/stdcopy-memcpy-memmove-optimizations) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285952/efficiency-of-stdcopy-vs-memcpy) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128430/why-is-stdcopy-5x-slower-than-memcpy-in-my-test-program) issues [copy vs. memcpy vs memmove](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2006/02/copy-confusion/)<sup>(excellent info here, btw.)</sup>, I have been reading up and it would seem to me, that **unlike** what is colloquially said, for example at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)<sub>Note: memcpy has been changed to memmove since taking this quote.</sub>  --

> #### Notes
>
> In practice, implementations of `std::copy` avoid multiple assignments
>   and use bulk copy functions such as `std::memcpy` if the value type is
>   `TriviallyCopyable`

-- `std::copy` (nor `std::copy_backward`) **cannot** be implemented in terms of `memcopy`, because for *`std::copy` only the beginning* of the destination range must not fall into the source range, but *for `memcpy` the entirety of the ranges* must not overlap.

Looking at Visual-C++'s implementation (see the `xutility` header), we can also observe that VC++ uses [memmove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove), but *that one* now has more relaxed requirements than `std::copy`:

> ... The objects may overlap: copying takes place as if the characters
>   were copied to a temporary character array and then the characters
>   were copied from the array ...

So it would appear that implementing `std::copy` in terms of `memcpy` is not possible, but using `memmove` is actually a pessimization. (a wee tiny bit of pessimization, possibly not measurable, but still)

**To come back to the question(s):** Is my summary correct? Is this a problem anywhere? *Regardless of what's specified*, is there even a possible practical implementation of `memcpy` that would not also fulfill the requirements of `std::copy`, i.e. are there `memcpy` implementations that break when the ranges partially overlap [as allowed](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2006/02/copy-confusion/) by `std::copy`?

Comment: First, the implementation of `std::copy` doesn't have to be strictly portable, and may utilize knowledge of the implementation details of `memcpy` (e.g. that it's actually OK to copy between overlapping regions, as long as they overlap the right way). Second, even if it chooses not to, it may still check ranges and defer to `memcpy` when they don't overlap (that is, most of the time).

Comment: libc++ and stdlibc++ call memmove as well, I changed that note on cppreference to say memmove.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19585930/321013

Comment: http://vgable.com/blog/2008/05/24/memcopy-memmove-and-speed-over-safety/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is, whether it's possible to encounter an efficient memcpy implementation with enough undefined behavior to not trust it over overlapping ranges, then the answer is yes. :-)

Consider one possible implementation of memcpy on Power(PC) architecture: lmw instruction will load multiple consecutive words from memory into consecutive registers (which can be specified as a user defined range argument). stmw will then save the supplied register range back to memory. Thus, we are talking around ~100/200 bytes (32b/64b CPU) buffered by the CPU during a single memcpy iteration - plenty of data to spoil the target range if it overlaps with the source one, especially considering that CPU makes no promises about relative order of individual load and stores.

Comment: How about a compiler which, given `void f(char *p,char*q) { if (p!=q) doSomething();} void g(char *p,char *q) { f(p,q); memcpy(p,q,sizeof *p); }` will infer that the Standard imposes no requirements on the behavior of g when p==q, thus allowing the call to "doSomething();" to be made unconditional?